# How to find the newest folder by name

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to copy some files (created by jenkins) from a specific folder on the server to another server. My Jenkins scripts creates backup folders something like backup-1, backup-2 and backup-3 `this is for the sake of example`

Now i want a script to copy the content of latest build `backup-3` in our example.

I know `ls -t1 backup* | head -n 1` but it output something like backup-3:

how can i remove the ":". notice that there are another folders and files besides backup* in the desired path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `-d, --directory` option.

> list directories themselves, not their contents

So `ls -t -1 --directory backup* | head -n 1`

Comment: `head: option requires an argument -- 'n'` or you could use `-1` without the n. Or could reverse the order with `-r` then use `tail -1`

Comment: You are right. I dropped the 1. Fixed.